# Jquery Zoom In Zoom Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make a zoom in zoom out buttons that will zoom in and zoom out on a picture that is inside a div. The problem is when press the zoom in or zoom out the picture goes out from the div. I think I'm not doing it right.

```
image.height = image.height+50
image.width= image.height+50
```

I would be grateful if anyone could give me any tips or code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple setup...

Check out this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/KGY7c/)

```
var imagesize = $('img').width();

$('.zoomout').on('click', function(){
    imagesize = imagesize - 5;
    $('img').width(imagesize);
});

$('.zoomin').on('click', function(){
    imagesize = imagesize + 5;
    $('img').width(imagesize);
});
```